# What charset encoding for an API

Tags: c#, json, zend-framework, utf-8, webclient

I have built an API in PHP with Zend Framework 1.x
For now there was only a webclient connecting to the API but we started developing a C# client.
I am experiencing an issue, here is how it works :

- User fills the form in the C# client
- C# sends the data with WebClient.UploadValues (Some values are added such as hmac of the parameteds, x-api-key, etc).
- The server receives the data
- The serveur converts the data to a json and creates the hmac from it
- The server compares the hmac sent and the hmac created

Here is where my problem is. Everything works fine if I send datawithout accents. But if there are, the Zend_Json::encode($params) returns a json encoded in UTF8 so the hmac created is not the same as the one sent.

So, I am wondering (as for some mysterious reason utf8_decode($json) does not work, should I find a way to compare the utf8 decoded json hmac of should I as the C# client to send all the parameters encoded in utf8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# client should send all parameters encoded in `UTF8`. You cannot run way from Unicode - UTF8 in JSON since the [definition of JSON](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) states:

> JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is
> UTF-8.

It could also be `UTF-16 (BE or LE)` or `UTF-32 (BE or LE)`.

If you generate JSON from the data and then get the hmac there should be a difference, right?
Since at the least JSON has two more symbols? `{` or `}` so should the hash be different than the one sent by the C# Client?

Either have the client send you the data in JSON or get the hmac before converting the data.

Comment: My C# client creates a json from the data and create the hmac from it. The server does the same. What I have done, as my C# doesn't send utf8 encoded caracters, is that I have used the php json_encode instead of the zend framework buildin. The php json_encode takes a parameter (json_encode($params, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)) so it does not encode in utf8. It works. But is it a problem? (security issue, etc)

Comment: I cannot determine if there is a security risk or not based on this data.
Encoding/decoding JSON is not a security risk on its own. ;)